# Parent form-child from communication OR relation OR validation

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

*I think this question has already been asked in complex terms. But I'm trying to make it simple here*.

---

I have a **parent component** having ***form tag & Submit Button***. it has got a **child component** having an **input** `required field` with ***form tag & button***.

Now let's say I want to put ***`custom validation`*** to the **input field** that is ***`entered letters must be uppercase`*** which works fine. In short both validations work fine in child cmp.

*You can check & play here* => https://plnkr.co/edit/0iMTib?p=preview

*how can I enable parent's submit button*,
 ***OR***
*how can I make parent form valid*, 
     
***`if child form is valid?`***

***also consider with If I have more nested forms!***

> *Is there any relationship between parent's form and child's form in **ANGULAR2*** ???

Answer (score 0):

You can emit child form status when `valueChanges` and add some logic to the parent form to check for that:

```
<child (valid)="childValid($event)"></child>
```

For more complex use cases I'd suggest using global app state to hold form status/values, which then can be accessed from anywhere in your application. Here's an example that uses `@ngrx/store`: [gist](https://gist.github.com/sasxa/c2618f7f566d42751b43).

Comment: I know that way. But let's say what If I have multi child cmps having form. What to do in that case? Also I dont wanna go with `@Input @Output-EventEmitter` mechanism. There gotta be some way to access child form through parent form.

Comment: And please check console. I'm already using `valueChanges` in child cmp. But that doesn't seem to be the final solution. I guess but not sure In `angular1` some way is there.

Comment: If you have many ot them, I'd suggest some app-state technique... `@ngrx/store`, for example. I didn't experiment with nested forms, seams clunky to me, app-state is much cleaner...

Comment: Would you please give me any kind of reference for `app-state`? any link or example or something?

Comment: Basically you create object `forms` and keep relevant data (like, status or even values) for all forms there. Then use that for UI checks. [@ngrx/store](https://github.com/ngrx/store) is redux-like implementation for app-state. I'm using [this](https://gist.github.com/sasxa/c2618f7f566d42751b43) to manage my forms, for example...

Comment: In that gist example (it uses @ngrx/store), I can access any form from anywhere in my app via app-state `this.store.value.forms.projects.valid`...